# Differences "so-called" and "called"

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

I really wonder if I express "**so-called**" in a sentence, can I also use "**called**" for the same way?

For example:

> The new technique **so-called** "blablabla" is to consume a lot of energy.

Can I write like:

> The new technique **called** "blablabla" is to consume a lot of energy.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First of all, *so-called* cannot be used as a verb, as in your first example; it is an adjective.

Secondly, *so-called* is used for two possible meanings: first, to give a "popular name" for a thing that has a different "proper name", such as

> the so-called 'splat' character (that is, the asterisk: *)

Or it can be used to indicate that you are going to refer to something with a name that you think is actually an improper or invalid name:

> my so-called friend just told the teacher I cheated.

(You are referring to someone as a friend, but the use of "so-called" indicates that you think that their behavior demonstrates that they aren't really your friend.)

Thus you should not write your sentence with "so-called" at all.  Use "called" to inform people of the proper name of the technique.

Comment: `So-called` would be correct in that phrase is it ran something like "This so-called "Extra-Green-Savings-Propulsions(tm)" technique will actually consume a lot of energy." But I admit that is stretching it :P

Comment: I think the unifying feature is that "so-called" puts what the thing is called slightly at arms length. The meaning is held between thumb and forefinger rather than being adopted.